# Folder.Items Resulting in Runtime error 13: Type mismatch

Tags: vba, outlook, type-mismatch

I have a folder in Outlook named "Questionnaire", and within that folder, I have several subfolders. The code loops through all the subfolders, within each subfolder, it finds all the unread items (specifically emails) and does something with the emails.

When the code is run on my coworker's computer, a Type Mismatch error is triggered at the line

```
Set objMails = olFolder2.Items
```

Similar threads point to an item that is non-mail causing the mismatch error. I confirmed with my coworker that there are no items other than emails in the subfolder. I tested on my own Outlook by dragging a calendar invite into the first subfolder, and the error occurred at the line

```
For Each objMail In objMails
```

Which would makes a lot more sense if the problem was to be stemming from having a non-mail item in the subfolder.

Here is a skeleton of my code:

```
'Define outlook folder variables
Dim olFolder1 As Outlook.Folder, olFolder2 As Outlook.Folder
Set olFolder1 = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Questionnaire")

For Each olFolder2 In olFolder1.Folders     'Loop through all the folders in the Questionnaire folder
    
    Dim objMails As Outlook.Items
    Set objMails = olFolder2.Items
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    sFilter = "[UNREAD]=TRUE"
    Set objMails = objMails.Restrict(sFilter)
    
    For Each objMail In objMails
        'CODE TO DO SOMETHING WITH EACH EMAIL IN THE SUBFOLDERS
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type Mismatch in Loop to scan Outlook Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701705/type-mismatch-in-loop-to-scan-outlook-messages)

Answer (score 1):

```
'escape multiple declaration in each loop iteration
Dim objMails As Outlook.Items
Dim objMail 'As Object
sFilter = "[UNREAD]=TRUE"
For Each olFolder2 In olFolder1.Folders
  Set objMails = olFolder2.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
  For Each objMail In objMails
    If objMail.Class = olMail Then
      'CODE TO DO SOMETHING WITH EMAIL only  
    End if
  Next objMail 'explicit loop variable
Next olFolder2 'explicit loop variable
```

Comment: Hi artnib, thank you for your response, I will try it out next Monday when I am in the office and see if works! Could you also help elucidate why my original code was running into the bug?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming you can only have `MailItem` objects in the folder. Declare `objMail`  variable as a generic `Object` rather than `MailItem`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dmitry! I have tried artnib's answer below and it worked, I guess even though I thought the .mailitem wasn't a problem, it was. Thanks again for your help and input.